# dataTransfer.getData('text') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to follow the html5 drag and drop tutorial at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-dataTransfer

The html is:

```
 <div id="words">
    <p class="word" draggable="true">word1</p>
    <p class="word" draggable="true">word2</p>
    <p class="word" draggable="true">word3</p>
 </div>
```

The js is:

```
var dragSrcEl = null;  
function handleDragStart(e) {
this.style.opacity = '0.4'; // this / e.target is the source node.
dragSrcEl = this;
e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.inneHTML); 
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
if (e.preventDefault) {
e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
}

e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; 

return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
// this / e.target is the current hover target.
this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
// this / e.target is current target element.

if (e.stopPropagation) {
e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
}
if (dragSrcEl != this) {
// Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
//this.innerHTML = temp;
}
return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
// this/e.target is the source node.

[].forEach.call(words, function (word) {
word.classList.remove('over');
});
}


var words = document.querySelectorAll('#words .word');
[].forEach.call(words, function(word) {
    word.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    word.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    word.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    word.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    word.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
    word.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

css is:

```
    .word{
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
cursor:move;
}
.word.over{
color: #ff0000;
}
```

However, when test the code in all browsers or jsfiddle, the target word changes fine, but the original word changes to "undefined"
I'm thinking it's because

```
dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
```

is working but

```
this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
```

returns undefined, and tests in jsfiddle confirmed this.

So why is

```
e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
```

return undefined?

Its value should be setted at

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.inneHTML);
```

isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the replace part to this

```
var temp = this.innerHTML;
this.innerHTML = dragSrcEl.innerHTML;
dragSrcEl.innerHTML = temp;
```

Demo: `http://jsfiddle.net/fWq4T/`

Comment: That's my backup plan, but I prefer making dataTransfer to work because Firefox needs dataTransfer to do DnD. This backup plan doesn't work on FF.

Comment: I have tried my sent jsfiddle also on FF and it works, could you please do it also.

Comment: You're right, it works! Thanks. But I'm still wondering why dataTransfer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change line #5

```
 e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.inneHTML);
```

to

```
 e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
```

Hope this help